# Use Perl to remove blocks of text from a file between two mark points

Tags: perl

I need to cut a set of lines from a file between two mark points. For example the file is

**file.txt**

```
END  
line 1 not removed  
END  
line 2 not removed  
line 3 not removed  
BEGIN  
line 1 is to be removed  
line 2 is to be removed  
line 3 is to be removed  
END  
line two last not removed  
END  
line three last not removed  
line four last not removed
```

I want to remove the lines between `BEGIN` and `END`. The new file becomes

**file2.txt**

```
END  
line 1 not removed  
END  
line 2 not removed  
line 3 not removed  
line two last not removed  
END  
line three last not removed  
line four last not removed
```

This means `BEGIN` and the first `END` after `BEGIN` and the lines between them should be removed.

I was able to write this program, and it works perfectly. But is there any better way to do this?

```
use File::Copy;

$j = $i = 0;

open(DATA,  "<file1.txt");
open(DATA1, ">file2.txt");

while (<DATA>) {
  if ($_ =~ /^BEGIN/) { $i = 1; }
  if ($_ =~ /^END/ && $i == 1) { $i = 0; next if $_ }
  if ($i == 1) { next if $_; }
  print DATA1 $_;
}

close(DATA);
close(DATA1);

copy "file2.txt", "file1.txt";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
while(<DATA>) {

  print DATA1 $_ unless /^BEGIN/ .. /^END/;
}
```

About the range `..` operator from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators),

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma) operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false. Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again.

Comment: It is abominable to recommend a Perl incantation for no reason other than that it gives the required result. I think it's clear from that excerpt from the documentation that the exact function of the range operators `..` and `...` is a little arcane. If anyone can explain concisely and intuitively whether the `BEGIN` line or the `END` line is printed, and what the difference is between `..` and `...` then please add to this wisdom.

Comment: @mpapec: You made no visible change in your revision so I have rolled it back

Comment: +1  This is perl as a "better sed."  (Indeed, the OP's whole program is simply `perl -ni -e 'print unless /^BEGIN/../^END/' file1.txt`.)  @Borodin, I usually think of `$here .. $there` as _"true from here to there, inclusive."_  I think of the extra dot in `...` as further indicating that _"here and there are far apart"_ (that is, they can't be the very same place), but I don't usually need that extra dot. :)